# PyCharm Terminal - use Git Bash

Tags: python, bash, terminal, pycharm

Goal: use Git Bash as Terminal in PyCharm.

**How can I have a normal Bash with Git integrated Terminal in PyCharm?**

File path for Git Bash: `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\git-bash.exe --cd-to-home`.

I apply Git Bash in PyCharm Settings:
[image: I apply Git Bash in PyCharm Settings.]

However, when I click `New Session` (new Terminal `+`), it launches as a Window:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are pointing at `git-bash.exe`, which is wrong. You should point at `bash.exe` which is located inside the bin folder. So your Shell path should be:

```
"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login
```

using

```
"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
```

would also work. Also works without `--login`. Make sure the `"` are there.